# UILongPressGesture detecting twice

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

In my longpress gesture i have an problem like,

```
*mypressrec = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                         initWithTarget:self 
                                         action:@selector(pressdetected:)];
    mypressrec.minimumPressDuration = 3;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:mypressrec];
    [mypressrec release];
```

my function:

```
    -(void)pressdetected:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{
     //My code goes here
  a=90;
   NSLog(@"value of my A",a);
}
```

here when i press for more than 3 seconds, the value of my A is printing **TWICE**. why it happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check the state of the UILongPressGestureRecognizer just add an if statement on the selector method:

```
- (void)pressdetected:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender { 
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    NSLog(@"Long press Ended");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Long press detected.");
}
}
```